# Ruby on Rails Mongoid to csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, mongoid

I would like to ask if any one know how correctly transfer Mongoid data in to CSV document?
I got a model Record and I want every row from Record to become row in CSV document. I got 90 columns (keys) in the Record and I want to exclude some of the them from CSV document but I do not wont manually type every key which I want to be on CSV document. My code is

```
 @all_rows = Record.all 
CSV.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'downloads', "file.csv"),  "w") do |csv|

   @allrows.all.each  do |record|
       csv << record
     end
```

But it does not work I am getting error

```
undefined method `map' for #<Record:0x007f9cd9e242f8>
```

if i adding `record.to_s` 
i am gating document full of records like this `#<Record:0x007f801ba60d68>`
If any one can please help me to fix it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `<<` method on csv ([documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-3C-3C)), which expects to be called with array as an argument. That is why it tries to perform `map` method on your record.

Solution for your problem is adding array of attributes instead of record object. There is method `attributes` that will return hash with all attributes.

```
ignored_attributes = ["attribute_you_dont_want", "another_attribute"]
@all_rows = Record.all 

CSV.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'downloads', "file.csv"),  "w") do |csv|
  @all_rows.each  do |record|
    csv << record.attributes.delete_if{ |attr, value| ignored_attributes.include?(attr) }.values
  end 
end
```

Note that I wrote `@all_rows.each`, you shouldn't call `all` method again.

This code will perform [delete_if](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if) method on attributes hash and will remove any attributes with names included in `ignored_attributes` array. `delete_if` returns hash on which you can call `values` method to return only array of values.

Comment: Thank you! It works! Do you know how I can get only `attributes` to create a headers, when I do `csv<<record.attributes` it gives error or what is the right way to insert data in to CSV document where headers have correct values in the columns. Because wright now I am getting very messy document. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yes, you can just write `Record.attribute_names - ignored_attributes`. Minus operation on arrays will return array without attributes from `ignored_attributes` array.